# How to recursively list folders in onedrive api?

Tags: api, onedrive

According to onedirve api documentation, in order to list folders in a directory for example root we use the following request:

```
GET /me/drive/root/children
```

In other apis such as dropbox there is an option where you can request the listing to be recursive for all the folders such that you get in the response the list of the folders and the folders inside the folders.

How can i do that in onedrive?

Comment: Are you wanting to target OneDrive Business, OneDrive Consumer, or both?

Comment: I think onedrive doesn't return that kind of Data. You have to use Loop for that If you want to display all file at a single time. Else you can  list specific folder as per click on that folder.